# microphone input listening on iOS, AVAudioRecorder or something else?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I'm wondering if there is a way to "listen" without recording and display the microphone's input levels?

Apples SpeakHere sample does the record and playback, and am wondering if there could a be a lighter version of just "listening" without actually recording and saving a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [AudioQueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for this purpose. In your callback, get the input level like so:

```
AudioQueueLevelMeterState meter[NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS];
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(meter);
AudioQueueGetProperty(aqInput, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB, meter, &dataSize);
// input 'level' is in meter.mAveragePower
```

And simply don't write the audio into a file.

Comment: On current devices, I believe it's always one, but if you have a USB audio interface hooked up on on iPad, it could conceivably be two. The safest thing to do is to query the audio device's channel configuration at runtime.